# Scroll to anchor with slash at the end

Tags: javascript, scroll, anchor

I have a website where sections have # and menu items should scroll to them. Due to setup of website it's required that my URL have / (slash) at the end.

For example website.com/about/

So anchor would be website.com/about/#team/

When there's / at the end of URL, scroll to anchor doesn't work. I don't have any jQuery on website so simple jump to section doesn't work either. When I remove / it works.

Is there jQuery which I can use for that purpose? I tried bunch of jQuery but without success.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Add smooth scrolling to all links
  $("a").on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var hash = this.hash;
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
    }, 800, function(){
         window.location.hash = hash;
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: _“Due to setup of website it's required that my URL have / (slash) at the end.”_ - how? We are talking about the fragment part of the URL here, that does not even get send to the server - so this must be a requirement you somehow implemented on the client side then? Or is the actual problem that your CMS / editor / whatever doesn’t allow you to specify other URL in the _content_, when you are inserting links there? It really sounds like you should rather fix _this_ problem, then try to find workarounds in other places.

Comment: The code you have shown simply gets the fragement part of the clicked link, and then tries to find an element with a corresponding ID in the document, to determine which position to scroll to. So that should already work fine, if you just removed the trailing slash from the value in the `hash` variable.

Comment: ` this.hash` holds the `#team` or `#team/` ?? if first then just put `window.location.hash = hash + '/''` as it requires / at the end

Comment: Use CSS `scroll-behavior: smooth;` and you're done. No JavaScript needed.

Comment: My URL structure needs to have / at the end. So `#team/` for example. I've tried adding `window.location.hash = hash + '/''` but it doesn't work.

Comment: @David Hi that is what i am telling. Keep your anchor tag as `#team` without **/** Then  `window.location.hash = hash + "/"`. So it would add slash at the end

Comment: @vipulpatel You're life safer :)!

Comment: @David if you could upvote the answer, would be great..

Comment: @vipulpatel - sorry, I made mistake. I have around 3000 URLs with / at the end so I can't manually delete / from the end. Can the code be modified to work with / at the end?

Comment: @David please see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said you cant change hash pattern then you have to do reverse process: **remove dash from this.hash before putting $(hash).offset() method**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  $('a').click(function(event) {

    // Store hash
    event.preventDefault();
    var hashWithoutDash = this.hash.replace("/",""); // remove dash from hash to make $(hashWithoutDash).offset() worked

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hashWithoutDash).offset().top
        }, 1000, function() {
          window.location.hash = this.hash; // keep actual hash with dash
      });
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="team">This is a paragraph.</p>

<div style ="height:1000px"> please scroll down to see href link </div>

<a href="#team/"> team </a>

<button>Return the offset coordinates of the p element</button>
```

Comment: Thanks! Can it be modified to work with load on new page like example.com/about/#team if I try visiting that link from example.com/ ?

Comment: you can achieve by`$(window).on('hashchange', function(e){
 // Your Code goes here
});`  And please vote or accept the answer if it been useful

Comment: Can you modify your answer since I couldn't get it to work with new update? Sure I'll do! You helped me a lot!

Comment: I'm more PHP developer I don't know much about jQuery. I don't know where to place what you've sent me in previous message.

Comment: I meant that you've added a comment To add on.hashchange and not being JavaScript developer I don't know how correctly to add it to the code you've posted and I marked as answer

Comment: You don't know how much I would appreciate if you could update the answer for fully working code :)!